# Is texts_to_sequences, pad_sequences available in TensorFlow.js or is there any other alternative for this?

Tags: javascript, python, keras, deep-learning, tensorflow.js

I have build a Keras model for next word prediction and I am trying to use my model in front-end for predicting next word based on input from the text field, I have to convert the following code from Python to JavaScript but did not find any suitable option.
Is there any way to work around this?

```
from keras.preprocessing.sequence import pad_sequences
input_text = input().strip().lower()

encoded_text = tokenizer.texts_to_sequences([input_text])[0]
pad_encoded = pad_sequences([encoded_text], maxlen=seq_len, truncating='pre')

for i in (model.predict(pad_encoded)[0]).argsort()[-10:][::-1]:
  pred_word = tokenizer.index_word[i]
  print("Next word suggestion:",pred_word)
```

I am getting the following predictions for **I** in **Python** :

- Next word suggestion: have
- Next word suggestion: am
- Next word suggestion: know
- Next word suggestion: think
- Next word suggestion: never
- Next word suggestion: do
- Next word suggestion: want
- Next word suggestion: ever
- Next word suggestion: will
- Next word suggestion: see

Answer (score 3):

I just wrote an alternative in node.js, maybe it can help you

Repo: https://github.com/Shadowhusky/node_tokenizer

You can install it with

```
npm install --save tf_node_tokenizer
```

Example:

```
const { Tokenizer } = require("tf_node_tokenizer");
const tokenizer = new Tokenizer({ num_words: 5, oov_token = "<unk>", });

const text = [
  "<start> Cake and frosting all over a face and hands tells a happy story.  <end>",
  "<start> A baby is feeding himself with his hands and is smeared with food. <end>",
  "<start> A baby eating pink dessert in a highchair <end>"
];

tokenizer.fitOnTexts(text);
tokenizer.texts_to_sequences(text);
```

Comment: Hello do you have any solution for pad_sequences?